# How to call phonegap application in native code for iphone

Tags: iphone, cordova

I developed one  static library application  "a" by use of phonegap framework for iphone and i want to include that static library  in another Xcode native project "b" .Is there anyone have idea then please guide me .Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select Targets & go to build phases, open copy headers section and move all headers files except .pch file from project to public section.

[image]

Go to Build Settings & in Packaging set Public Header Folder Path as $(PRODUCT_NAME) & in Deployment set Installation Directory as $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR).

[image]

[image]

Now click on cmd+b & in build folder you will be able to see all header files(.h) & library file(.a). Drag & drop those files in your native Xcode project and use them.